# Using curl to get a URL from the network

Tags: php, curl

Hi guys so i'm using a third party iframe and I would like to load that iframe "internally" or at backend? , once it is loaded a link would be fetch at the iframe and it's at the network, fetching a link from CDN and I would like to get that link and display it to the frontend. But i'm not quite sure if i'm using curl the right away or is there a better way.

(just in case)
Network = when you inspect your google tab you will see a tab called network

```
$filtering = "https://streamwebsite.com/movie/batman";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $filtering);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Quite hard to understand that phrasing. _“once it is loaded a link would be fetch at the iframe”_ - so you mean you want to extract a link from the document that currently gets loaded into an iframe? That’s basically _web scraping_ then, use that research keyword to read up on what the common approaches are.

Comment: oh i'm sorry still lack of experience especially in php, so you know when you load an iframe and at the same time you inspect the network at your browser? once that iframe loads and you click on play it fetches a link from CDN to bring it to the iframe? Yeah i want all these to be done in the backend but only show the CDN link at the frontend

Comment: So you are trying to “rip” the source URL of a video from a streaming website, so that you can play it inside your site, without the iframe, so that it appears as if it was actually your own content? Then you better forget about it, because that is likely to get quite complicated - such a streaming website surely has no interest whatsoever in you using _their_ content inside your site that way, so they will have measures in place against that.

Comment: Actually if you put it that way the third party i'm on is already doing that, so i'm going through 2 third party.... the only security measures i checked is only the token which is about 2 hours and the video will stop playing, what i meant by i'm going through 2 third party is 1st iframe get from 2nd iframe and 2nd iframe get it from the cdn

Comment: Still gonna refer you back to my first comment then - go start reading up on the basics of web scraping, and how to find elements/attributes once you got the HTML code - that second step usually involves a DOM parser.

Comment: Great thank you so much